# How do I know total suggested edits and edit posts count?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I want to know how many suggested edits I have approved or rejected so far? And also I want to know how many posts have been edited by me so far?

Is there any way to know the above counts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To know how many suggested edit have been approved by you

Go to any of the suggested edit review [you have reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1844566) -> Click on `(more)`

It will show Review Stats like this:

> Edwin Alex has approved 98 edit suggestions and rejected 1 edit suggestion

You can also see the history of your suggested edit review [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history)

---

To know how many posts have been edited by you

Go to User page -> Click on editors tab -> [filter with `all`](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all&search=Edwin%20Alex) and search for your name.

Also you can see details of posts revised by you from your profile.
Go to your profile -> activity tab -> [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060292/edwin-alex?tab=activity&sort=revisions)

Comment: thanks. but for total edited posts?

Comment: @EdwinAlex - See the updated answer.

Comment: Nice. Thank you so much..

Comment: with this answer we can't see the no. of succefull and rejected edits of our's, we can only see our history and others' no. of succefull and rejected edits

Comment: @Azik - Well, the OP didn't ask it. Did he?

Comment: ok, Now I ask it as a new question

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of ways to get this data.

You can go to your profile page > activity > [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060292/edwin-alex?tab=activity&sort=reviews) and choose one of your suggested edit reviews. This will take you to a specific suggested edit, if you click the [more link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1844567#), you will see details like this which shows the total approved and rejected:

[image]

If you want the total stats of all reviews then you can go to the review queue for [Suggested Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1845014), look at the [stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) page it will so you a total number of reviews that you have completed.  Or you can hover over the Badge Progress bar to see the total reviews:

[image]

Comment: no, I have only 205 successfull edits, 25 successfully edited posts were removed/migrated

Comment: @Azik Are you saying the stats are wrong?

Comment: I don't know the exact no. of  my successfull edits, but now I'm seeing 205 successful edits in my badge process

Comment: @Azik - Edits for badge progress doesn't count your own edits. :)

Comment: @hims056, in your answer we can't see the no. of succefull and rejected edits of our's

Comment: Azik - the image in bluefeet's post is of **his** stats :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop _her_ stats. :)

Comment: @bluefeet - Ohh I too didn't know this :D

Comment: Erm... wups. My apologies.

Comment: @RoryAlsop no problem, happens all the time.