# How do I know the number of rejected edits and total number of suggested edits of mine?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

I can see the history of my suggested edits in my profile and I can see the number of successfull edits made by me in the badge progress.

I can also see others' [number of rejected edits and total number of suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174934/how-do-i-know-total-suggested-edits-and-edit-posts-count).

But, How do I know the number of rejected edits and total number of suggested edits of mine?

Comment: check any of your suggested edit link, it will show you your suggested edit's approved & rejected both while clicking on "more" link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I know the number of rejected edits and total number of suggested edits of mine?

Go to any of the suggested edit review [(suggested by you)](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1844681) -> Click on `(more)`

It will show Review Stats like this:

> Editor Stats
>
> NAZIK had 230 edit suggestions approved, and 63 edit suggestions rejected

As you already mentioned, you can see the detailed suggested edits (suggested by you) from your [activity tab -> suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/756941/nazik?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

Comment: how did u get the link http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1844681

Comment: @Azik - From your activity tab. See the last sentence of my answer.